# How to correct image scaling for images that appear inline in text?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to embed an image (with a mathematical equation) in an HTML text such that the images scales with text, regardless of what font size is chosen.

Using a simple example image from Wikipedia, an example is shown at http://jsfiddle.net/7ds334hg/show/:

```
<p>There is a huge demand for long text. Therefore, this paragraph contains a couple of words that are not particularly interesting. Much more interesting is whether the image below is shown correctly. Hmm...</p>
<ul>
<li><p>The following letters should have roughtly the same size: X <img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/f5471531a3fe80741a839bc98d49fae862a6439a" alt="X" style="height:1.05em;vertical-align: -3px" /></p>
</li>
</ul>
```

I am giving an image height in "em" to make sure that the image scales well regardless of the actually chosen font size. In firefox and Chrome, th example works fine.

On Android (5.1.1), however, the image is rendered way too small:

[image: Screenshot]

Funnily, shortening the rubbish text makes the the page look correct (http://jsfiddle.net/7ds334hg/1/show/).

How can I fix this such that the images are scaled correctly on most devices?

Comment: Don't have an android device on hand but try to set image to display inline-block http://jsfiddle.net/7ds334hg/2/

Comment: @Huangism That unfortunately also doesn't work. https://imgur.com/a/Kn7hi - It's funny that your "100%" scale is still too small.

Comment: there is probably a simple solution but it seems I cannot simulate this on chrome so I have no access to an android device to view the issue, hopefully someone else can take care of it